# Multiple forum db structure

Tags: mysql, structure

What is the optimal multiple forum db structure?
I think to have one table with the name and description of the forums and another with posts,time of the post,users which has written the post and etc. and to relate `forums` and `posts` table.
What do you think?Is this a good decision?

Table `forums`:

```
|fid|desc|title|
```

Table `posts`

```
|id|post|user|time|fid|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short yes.  You would almost certainly want to separate forums and posts as they are relational by nature and this also gives you the ability to easily move posts from one forum to another, where they may be more relevant.

You will need a lot more tables and fields for a complete forum system however...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a good start although you're missing a lot of fields not to mention about 20 other tables

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. But i would rename the field `desc` of the table `forums` because it is a reserved word.

For more info have a look at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html